# flash file on an image in html

Tags: html, flash, image

I am trying to place a flash file on an image at a specific location. how can i do this?
i tried something like this

`<img src="images/logo.jpg"/> <object classid="homelogo"><embed src="images/logo.swf"></embed><object>`

bit it did not work. how can i overlap a flash file on top on an image at a specific location?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [flash file on an image in html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135182/flash-file-on-an-image-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

One way of trying this,

div#logo {position:absolute; left:100px; top:300px; z-index:2; width:100px; height:100px; background-image: url('images/logo.jpg');}

Add your flash component to div.

Comment: but then i have multiple usemaps for that image, so i cannot use it in css.